# How to apply extra fee on order / cart total in magento?

Tags: magento

I have a magento site in which I want to charge the customer with some extra fee per order.
This fee must be displayed under cart page & need to be added to subtotal & passed to all places including payment gateway. Any one have implemented this or is there custom module which supports this option.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Magento Extra Fee Extension](http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-extra-fee-extension/) which allows you to apply different types of extra charges like product or category specific addditial charges, order type fee, or shipping type fee, gift wrap fee etc.

Translating fee names in different languages or charging one time setup fee is something you should look at.

Answer (score 1):

Fooman has made an off-the-shelf extension that should do what you are looking for

http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-surcharge.html